# <form> element that posts to an <object> element

Tags: html, xhtml

Is it possible for a **form** to be posted to an **object** element, the same way that it can to an **iframe** (e.g. **form target="idOfIframe"**)? In an attempt to keep this page XHTML-strict compliant, I would like to avoid **iframe** if possible.

Comment: I know you could do it with a script....

Comment: @bdares — Such as one that uses XHR to post the data, then converts the response to a data: URI, and then generates a new `<object>` using that for the data, then replacing the old object with it? I suppose that would work. The ROI would be relatively awful, but it would probably work (so long as JS was available in the browser).

Comment: @Quentin I didn't say "should" :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't.

`<object>` elements are for embedding external media. They don't support the interactive features of iframes.

If you need the functionality of an iframe, then switch to Transitional (or the HTML 5 draft).

Comment: It would have been a pretty stupid suggestion for me to make if it didn't. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element

Comment: Well that page only deals with HTML5, not XHTML5 - or are all HTML5 elements inherently valid in XHTML5?

Comment: XHTML5 is just HTML5 expressed in XML instead of HTML 5's "SGML-like language with custom parse rules".

Comment: I'd recommend against XHTML on the web in general though, it is usually more trouble then it is worth.

Comment: Thanks - I've actually had much success with XHTML (IE<8 is now a small portion of the browser market - I don't support IE7 anymore and I provide conditional compatibility scripts for IE8). I find it extremely useful (not to mention neat and clean) to be able to code with XSL templates and XML files for page content (with server-side applications just adding any additional data to the XML DOM before transformation).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7696/discussion-between-aaron-j-spetner-and-quentin)